# Why apache.commons.logging.Log won't log Debug level?

Tags: java, apache, logging, log4j

I have a J2SE desktop app, and I'm trying to understand how to use apache commons logging. I have the following properties file in my project, using latest apache commons logging:

commons-logging.properties:

```
org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger

#Priorities are: DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, or FATAL.
log4j.rootCategory=DEBUG
log4j.appender.appender.Threshold=DEBUG
```

log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=TRACE
```

logging.properties:

```
# jdk handlers
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler java.util.logging.FileHandler

# default log level FINE=ERROR FINER= FINEST=
.level=FINEST
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=FINEST

# log file name for the FileHandler
java.util.logging.FileHandler.pattern=gef_debug.log
```

And, even everything set to FINEST or TRACE, I still only the log for info and error on my console.

Any idea what's wrong here?

--

by the way, I'm in a existing old project, so maybe there's some configuration somewhere that I don't know about, that is blocking my log... :/
But only for the DEBUG level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`org.apache.commons.logging.Log= org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Jdk14Logger`

I think this line  means you are using **Jdk14Logger, not Log4j**.

Jdk14Logger reads the file **log-config.properties**. Just create it in the application classpath and set it up. For example:

```
# The following creates the console handler
handlers=java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
# Set the default logging level for the root logger
.level=FINEST
# Set the default logging level
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level=ALL

# Set the default formatter
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter=java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
```

You can also change the logger to Log4j by changing the first line of the **commons-logging.properties** to `org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger`.

By doing so you'll be using Log4J logger that reads from the **log4j.properties** so you'll need to add the console handler to it.

You can take a look to several log implementations [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-logging/apidocs/org/apache/commons/logging/impl/package-summary.html).

Comment: `commons-logging.properties` was an eye-opener, but the problem is even if I do `org.apache.commons.logging.Log=org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger`, I get `User-specified log class 'org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger' cannot be found or is not useable.`.